# wchar_t **WinList Dynamic pointer array to character array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I'm having issues trying to store wchar_t character arrays in a global array,
below is the code for what i want to do: -

```
wchar_t **WinList //Global array store

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int NumMembers;

    if (WinList == nullptr)
    {
        NumMembers = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        NumMembers = (sizeof(**WinList) / sizeof(wchar_t));
    }

    wchar_t class_name[300];

    GetClassName(hwnd, class_name, 300);

    WinList = new wchar_t * [NumMembers + 1];
    WinList[NumMembers] = class_name;

    return TRUE;
}
```

The error:

`Unhandled exception at 0x765CE2C3 (usp10.dll) in Win32Project4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD." is occuring below at the TextOut function, WinList = 0x002802a0 {0xcdcdcdcd <Error reading characters of string.>} : -`

```
case WM_PAINT:
    if (WinList != nullptr)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop != sizeof(WinList); iLoop++)
        {
            TextOut(hDC, 5, iLoop*10, WinList[iLoop], (sizeof(WinList[iLoop]) / sizeof(wchar_t)));
        }
    }
    break;
```

I have tried various variations of functions and code using things like malloc and mcscpy. I seem to however be misunderstand the scope of the pointer I think. I do not seem to be able to get my head around it. Any explanation would be much appreciated. I'm using VS 2013, and this is more of a learning concept rather than is there a better way. However I would also appreciate the 'better way' solution.

Regards,

HonkeyPig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you store result of the call-back function in local variable that is immediately discarded on return..

Besides that

```
(sizeof(**WinList) / sizeof(wchar_t))
```

is `exactly sizeof(pointer)/2` that is 2 on a 32 bit architecture....